# modesetting driver with AccelMethod glamor - tty Problem

Tags: drivers, 20.04, login, tty, ubuntu-drivers

I switched my system (Xubuntu 20.04.05 LTS) from the intel driver to the modesetting driver with AccelMethod glamor. If I start my system, everything works well, the system shows still the graphics screen. The problem begins when I press CTRL + ALT + F1 to call the console tty1. In this case the display shows still the last graphics screen. I must press a key for getting the login screen of tty1 shown.

The screen output isn’t updated after switching to tty1 in the first step. Did you ever encounter this problem?

Even more strange is the fact that calling one of the other consoles tty2 to tty6 works in part. If I press e. g. CTRL + ALT + F2 the login screen of tty2 is shown after 5 seconds.

Comment: Please review your question. There is no such version of XUbuntu.

Comment: Sorry, Xubuntu 20.04.05 LTS is correct..